# Browserify with jQuery plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, browserify

I'm trying to get some jQuery plugins to work with browserify.  I have my package.json setup like this:

```
  "browser": {
    "jquery": "./client/js/vendors/jquery-2.2.2.min.js",
    "jquery-validation": "./client/js/vendors/jquery.validate.js"
  },
  "browserify-shim": {
    "jquery": "global:$"
  },
```

However, when I `require('jquery-validation')`, I get cannot read property `fn` of undefined as it relates to this plugin.   I'm trying to also have it so that `$` will be global as it's used all over, without having to require it.

I've seen so many different articles and configs for this, but nothing seems to work.

Any suggestions or clarity would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

I also sometimes get `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'jquery'`

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need to shim jquery, it's conpatible with node yoo can simply install it with `npm install jquery --save` and make `var $= require("jquery")` in your code.
2. Yo do need to shim jquery.validate.

package.json:

```
{  
   "browser":{  
      "jquery-validation":"./node_modules/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"
   },
   "browserify-shim":{  
      "jquery-validation":{  
         "depends":[  
            "jquery:jQuery"
         ]
      }
   },
   "browserify":{  
      "transform":[  
         "browserify-shim"
      ]
   },
   "dependencies":{  
      "jquery":"^2.0.0",
      "jquery-validation":"^1.15.1"
   }
}
```

Note: jquery.validate depend on jQuery version 2.0^ ( you can see in the package.json file of the jquery-validation's npm package ) so you have to set dependency on jquery ^2.0 in your project otherwise jquery-validation will load he's own version of jQuery and integration will not work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have typo, you should call `require('jquery-validation')` instead of `require('jquery-validate')`

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo in my question.